# Libvirt with Xen fails to start correctly Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, xen, libvirt

At the moment i'M really feeling a little helpless:

I tried to setup Ubuntu 14.04 with Xen and libvirt for management.
I created a VM but I did not auto-start (altough autostart is checked).
If I do a "stop libvirt-bin" and "start libvirt-bin" the VM start perfectly.

What seems to me a little bit strange is that libvirt-bin is starting BEFORE the Xen daemon.

**Boot.log:**

```
 * Starting configure network device security                            [ OK ]
 * Starting configure network device                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting libvirt daemon                                               [ OK ]
 * Starting Xen daemons                                                                [ OK ]
```

as a workaround i added the start/stop command to the rc.local

Any ideas on this?
Is the starting order correct?

Answer (score 2):

Heres my solution,  You are right about xen needing to running before libvirt-bin. The problem for me is the fact that xen is using systemV and libvirt-bin using upstart.   After much debate i decided i had to go with one or the other.

I wanted to ensure i didn't touch the actual supplied scripts as they may get updated from time to time AND I wanted to ensure the safe startup and shutdown would still come in to effect.

Upstart Won. -  Disable XEN SystemV scripts on Boot first using the following

```
sudo update-rc.d xen disable
sudo update-rc.d xendomains disable
```

then edit **/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf** and amend the pre-start with ***exec /etc/init.d/xen start***. It only starts ONCE on start up, and any preceeding restarts of the service will just tick a "Service already running" responce.

**Example below**

```
description "libvirt daemon"
author "Dustin Kirkland <kirkland@canonical.com>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

expect daemon
respawn

# daemonize
env libvirtd_opts="-d"
# whether libvirtd should run at boot/shutdown
env start_libvirtd="yes"
# by default wait 30 seconds for vms to shut down
env libvirtd_shutdown_timeout=30
# uris for which to shut down vms
env libvirt_uris='qemu:///system lxc:///'

pre-start script
 [ -r /etc/default/libvirt-bin ] && . /etc/default/libvirt-bin
 [ ! "x$start_libvirtd" = "xyes" ] && { stop; exit 0; }
 mkdir -p /var/run/libvirt
 # Clean up a pidfile that might be left around
 rm -f /var/run/libvirtd.pid
 # -----------------------------------
 exec /etc/init.d/xen start
 # -----------------------------------
end script

pre-stop script
 [ -r /etc/default/libvirt-bin ] && . /etc/default/libvirt-bin

 log_msg()
 {
  logf="/var/log/libvirt/shutdownlog.log"
  logger -p daemon.debug -s -t libvirt -- "$@" >> $logf 2>&1
 }

 run_virsh()
 {
  # We parse the output for things like domain state;
  # make sure the output is in the language we expect.
  LANG=C virsh "$@"
 }

 if [ -z "$RUNLEVEL" ]; then
  exit 0
 fi

 if [ "$RUNLEVEL" -ne 0 ] && [ "$RUNLEVEL" -ne 1 ] && [ "$RUNLEVEL" -ne 6 ]; then
  exit 0
 fi
 log_msg "libvirt-bin: entering pre-stop at $(date)"

 for uri in $libvirt_uris; do
  for domain in $(run_virsh -c "$uri" list | awk '$3 == "running" {print $2}'); do
   log_msg "libvirt-bin: attempting clean shutdown of $domain at $(date)"
   run_virsh -c "$uri" shutdown "$domain" >/dev/null
  done
 done

 delay=$libvirtd_shutdown_timeout
 while [ $delay -gt 0 ]; do
  for uri in $libvirt_uris; do
   if ! run_virsh -c "$uri" list | awk '$3 == "running" {exit 1}'; then
    # VMs at this URI are still running. Wait, then
    # start at the beginning looking for running VMs.
    sleep 1
    delay=$(($delay - 1))
    continue 2
   fi
  done
  break
 done

 for uri in $libvirt_uris; do
  for domain in $(run_virsh -c "$uri" list | awk '$3 == "running" {print $2}'); do
   log_msg "destroying $domain"
   run_virsh -c "$uri" destroy "$domain" >/dev/null
  done
 done
 log_msg "libvirt-bin: exiting pre-stop at $(date)"
end script

# /etc/default/libvirt-bin will be deprecated soon.
# If you used to set $libvirtd_opts in /etc/default/libvirt-bin,
# change the 'exec' line here instead.
script
 [ -r /etc/default/libvirt-bin ] && . /etc/default/libvirt-bin
     exec /usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts
end script
```

Thats it.  Restart your server,  and you should be running.

Hope that helps,  or at least puts you in the right direction.

Comment: You said "I wanted to ensure i didn't touch the actual supplied scripts", but then you edited libvirt-bin.conf. Isn't that touching a supplied script?